# Not able to hit controller with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can anyone please help me as I am not able to hit the controller for one of my URLs.  Here is the code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository repository;
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listPosts(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("posts", repository.findAll());
        return "postList";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newProject() {
        return "newPost";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@RequestParam("postDescription") String comment) {
        repository.save(new Posts());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/postList");
    }
    //...
}
```

and the JSP:

```
<form action="<spring:url value="/posts/create" />">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="postDescription">Post</label>
     <button type="submit" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I'm able to hit `RegistrationController` but  not `PostController`.

Do I need to configure something else?

Comment: /create is POST type. May be you forgot to put `method=POST` in the form

Comment: No i put the method post on same

Comment: <form  action="<spring:url value="/posts/create" />" method="POST">
           <div class="form-group">
                <label for="postDescription">Post</label>
                <textarea class="form-control custom-control" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea> 
       
            </div> 
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>

Comment: this is my mvc config class.

Comment: What URL are you trying?

Comment: Did you try change from  <spring:url value="/posts/create" > to value="/posts/create"

Comment: try changing @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST) to @RequestMapping(value = "/posts/create", method = RequestMethod.POST) and remove the @RequestMapping at the class level just to see if it works. I've had trouble with that stuff, evenly getting it right after playing around with it a bit.